# Dropdown header from hover to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code inside our header to display our cart.
Currently the dropdown is displayed on hover.

How can I modify this so that the dropdown is displayed `onclick`?

```
<a href="#header-cart" class="skip-link skip-cart <?php if($_cartQty <= 0): ?> no-count<?php endif; ?>">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="count"><?php echo $_cartQty; ?></span>
</a>

<div id="header-cart" class="block block-cart skip-content">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_content');?>
</div>
```

I use this code for the dropdown on the website:

```
    <?php //Drop-down ?>
    var ddOpenTimeout;
    var dMenuPosTimeout;
    var DD_DELAY_IN = 200;
    var DD_DELAY_OUT = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_IN = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_OUT = 0;

    $('.clickable-dropdown > .dropdown-heading').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().trigger('mouseenter');
    });

    //$('.dropdown-heading').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-heading', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.dropdown', function() {

        var ddToggle = $(this).children('.dropdown-heading');
        var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
        var ddWrapper = ddMenu.parent(); <?php //$(this); ?>

        <?php //Clear old position of dd menu ?>
        ddMenu.css("left", "");
        ddMenu.css("right", "");

        <?php //Show dd menu ?>
        if ($(this).hasClass('clickable-dropdown'))
        {
            <?php //If dropdown is opened (parent already has class 'open') ?>
            if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
            {
                $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <?php //Add class 'open' to dd ?>
            clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout);
            ddOpenTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                ddWrapper.addClass('open');

            }, DD_DELAY_IN);

            //$(this).addClass('open');
            $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
        }

        <?php //Set new position of dd menu.
              //This code is delayed the same amount of time as drop-down animation. ?>
        clearTimeout(dMenuPosTimeout);
        dMenuPosTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

            if (ddMenu.offset().left < 0)
            {
                var space = ddWrapper.offset().left; <?php //Space available on the left of dd ?>
                ddMenu.css("left", (-1)*space);
                ddMenu.css("right", "auto");
            }

        }, DD_DELAY_IN);

    }).on('mouseleave', '.dropdown', function() {

        var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
        clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout); <?php //Clear, to close dd on mouseleave ?>
        ddMenu.stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_OUT).fadeOut(DD_ANIMATION_OUT, "easeInCubic");
        if (ddMenu.is(":hidden"))
        {
            ddMenu.hide();
        }
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `'mouseenter' --> 'click'` , as 'click' will do it for you with significantly less brain damage. Still I see that your problem statement is not complete If you want complete solution for what you want to achieve,then perhaps you have to give some more details on the problem statement as the statement what you want to achieve and please provide the full html. Use Fiddler and upload the html and scripts and share the link.

Comment: Thanks! But only onclick does display the div. But when clicking again the dropdown does not hide. This only hide when the mouse leave the div. How can I edit this, so that the drown will only be closed by clicking again?

Comment: @Jelle change `mouseleave` to `click`... it seems to me that you don't have a working understanding of what's going on in there, you should be solving that first

Comment: well if he changes it to click it will do nothing since there are two click handler on the same container. one for showing, one for hiding.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4aj02qs9/1/ check this one, may be you want something like this

Answer (score 1):

change this line `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.dropdown', function() {`

to `$(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function() {`

you should probably remove the `on('mouseleave')` function completely and put it into your click logic

**EDIT** here is a complete solution in one JS (and please dont use a `<?php` tag for commenting )

```
    var ddOpenTimeout;
    var dMenuPosTimeout;
    var DD_DELAY_IN = 200;
    var DD_DELAY_OUT = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_IN = 0;
    var DD_ANIMATION_OUT = 0;

    $('.clickable-dropdown > .dropdown-heading').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        $(this).parent().trigger('mouseenter');
    });

    //$('.dropdown-heading').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-heading', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {

            var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
            clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout); <?php //Clear, to close dd on mouseleave ?>
            ddMenu.stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_OUT).fadeOut(DD_ANIMATION_OUT, "easeInCubic");
            if (ddMenu.is(":hidden"))
            {
                ddMenu.hide();
            }
            $(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
            var ddToggle = $(this).children('.dropdown-heading');
            var ddMenu = $(this).children('.dropdown-content');
            var ddWrapper = ddMenu.parent();


            ddMenu.css("left", "");
            ddMenu.css("right", "");

            if ($(this).hasClass('clickable-dropdown'))
            {
                if ($(this).hasClass('open'))
                {
                    $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                clearTimeout(ddOpenTimeout);
                ddOpenTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                    ddWrapper.addClass('open');

                }, DD_DELAY_IN);

                //$(this).addClass('open');
                $(this).children('.dropdown-content').stop(true, true).delay(DD_DELAY_IN).fadeIn(DD_ANIMATION_IN, "easeOutCubic");
            }
            clearTimeout(dMenuPosTimeout);
            dMenuPosTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                if (ddMenu.offset().left < 0)
                {
                    var space = ddWrapper.offset().left; <?php //Space available on the left of dd ?>
                    ddMenu.css("left", (-1)*space);
                    ddMenu.css("right", "auto");
                }

            }, DD_DELAY_IN);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! But only onclick does display the div. But when clicking again the dropdown does not hide. This only hide when the mouse leave the div. 

How can I edit this, so that the drown will only be closed by clicking again?

Comment: You can set a boolean whether the dropdown is opened or not and check it inside the onclick function to whether open or close it.

Comment: i updated the fiddle to your needs. you can simply check if the `.dropdown` has class `open` or not. and depending on the result you can do what you need